# Serial downvoting detected - SE scripts are "silent"

Tags: discussion, support

I detected that somebody serially downvoted my random answers on Academia.SE (see picture below). However, no action occurred from SE software, which supposedly detects and reverses such hostile actions (in addition to punishing the attacker). What should be my next steps?

---

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it takes a few days to detect the pattern.

Comment: @StrongBad: I see. Then I will wait a little - there is certainly no rush with this. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/255554) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212332/255554) on Meta.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Thank you for referencing the links.

Comment: Those are all on answers to closed questions. I suspect someone downvoted them to make the questions easier to delete (require fewer votes to delete.) So it's probably not personal (for what it's worth...)

Comment: @ff524: Thank you for your comment. Even it's not personal, I think that it is totally unacceptable to manipulate votes for any purposes. Not to mention that closed questions should IMHO stay closed and not being targeted for deletion at all (for many reasons, including a drastic difference in complexity of reopening deleted questions vs. closed ones).

Comment: @ff524 I've been noticing this pattern on a number of my answers as well.  Not enough that I felt it worth raising, but if it's happening widely, it may be worth a discussion.

Comment: @jakebeal You can raise a meta post to discuss if you want... but even if there is a consensus that downvoting in order to delete is an inappropriate use of voting, there isn't anything we (mods or anyone else) can do to enforce it. The only tools we have to identify inappropriate voting habits are for identifying votes that target a particular user.

Comment: Top tip: don't answer crap questions. Deletion of crap is an important part of how the site works. Answering crap questions encourages the asking of more bad questions, as well as hindering their deletion. When one answers a question that's too broad or off-topic, one worsens site quality. Please be part of the solution, not part of the problem.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Thank you for the tip - will keep that in mind. However, I'm not sure how it is related to serial downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial downvotage appears to have been fixed by now:

[image: rep]

The remaining downvotes (three on a single question) can't really come from a single user.

Do you want to accept this answer or self-answer and accept, just so we see this has been resolved?

Comment: Stephan, I'm gladly upvoting and accepting your answer. Your help (and others, if any) is much appreciated. Best regards, Alex.

Comment: The downvoted answers no longer appear in that reputation history because the questions they were posted on are deleted, not because votes were reversed. [It looks something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) when votes are reversed.